# Pressing Windows+Back navigates back instead of clearing text field

Tags: macos, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

In Firefox on Mac OS X, there's a major drawback. Pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>Back</kbd> while in a text edit box will navigate backwards instead of positioning the caret at the beginning of the line being edited.

How do I correct this misbehavior?

Comment: Why is there a Windows key on your Mac? Are you using a Windows keyboard? Have you remapped Windows to Command?

Comment: just using a windows keyboard. It escapes me right now its name in Mac world - it sits right between the [ctrl] and [alt] keys.

Comment: I've never used a mac keyboard, so forgive my possible ignorance here, but isn't that what the `home` key is for?